# Chrome javascript Proxy object is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, proxy

I wanted to experiment with the Proxy object that was introduced in EMCAScript 6, as described in this blogpost: http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/07/es6-and-proxy.html

However when I wanted to run the example code:

```
var engineer = { name: 'Joe Sixpack', salary: 50 };

var interceptor = {
  set: function (receiver, property, value) {
    console.log(property, 'is changed to', value);
    receiver[property] = value;
  }
};

engineer = Proxy(engineer, interceptor);
```

I got the error that Proxy is not defined. Does anybody know more about the support for proxies in Chrome? I am using Chrome version 33.0.1750.152 on a Mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if you’re using Chrome most of the ES6 features are hidden behind a feature toggle. Browse to chrome://flags, find the section titled “Enable Experimental JavaScript” and enable it to turn on support: chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony

After activation, restart your chrome browser and it should work

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore in the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: v8 (the javascript engine behind Chrome) people implemented it and then removed it due to some security stuff. They are re-implementing it now.

Answer (score 2):

V8 released full support for `Proxy` in 4.9

Source; http://v8project.blogspot.de/2016/01/v8-release-49.html

Chrome 49 uses V8 4.9

Answer (score 1):

Just start chrome from command line with flag `--js-flags="--harmony-proxies"` or add it to chrome's shortcut

Answer (score -1):

There is a Chrome specific shim for Proxy available at https://github.com/anywhichway/chrome-proxy. If your needs are basic, this should get you by until the v8 team finishes re-implementation.